# SQL Server 2012 : get number of occurrences and calculate duration with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, count, dynamic-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of a Process Setpoint and Process Value (PV).

Something like below table:

```
    Timestamp       Setpoint             PV 
    ---------       ---------       -------------
    t1                  100             125
    t2                  100              95  *
    t3                  100              98
    t4                  100              88
    t5                  100             105 
    t6                  100              59  *
    t7                  100              90
    t8                  100             101
    t9                  100              70  *
    t10                 100             101
```

What I want to do, is a query to create one row as result to count number of times that PV went below the Setpoint and comes back above the setpoint. and also calculate the duration of time that it was below setpoint.

**Result** should be like this.

```
    NumberofOccurance       Duration
    ------------------      ---------
            3               (t5-t2)+(t8-t6)+(t10-t9)
```

**Note:** Correct number of occurrence is **3** in this case not **6**
and I think the hardest part is doing the duration.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Edit:  I kind of get couple of good answers below, but, what about if I have more than one PV( I actually have 10 different PV in separate columns and two Setpoints in two separate columns for each PV which is 20 columns for setpoint. 
all are in one table. Timestamp in 1 second intervals.
Any idea how I can do the same query for every single PV ?
I am thinking about Dynamic SQL with Cursor and CTE option below all combined together. but it is really difficult.

Comment: What your SQL Server version?

Comment: Alex, it is MSSQL

Comment: I need (it would be helpful) the specific version.

Comment: Ok, it is MSSQL 2012 version 11,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long and ugly but it works

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
  (
     TimeSt   INT,
     SetPoint INT,
     PV       INT
  )

INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES      (1,             100,             122),
            (2,             100,             95),
            (3,             100,             98),
            (4,             100,             88),
            (5,             100,             105),
            (6,             100,             59),
            (7,             100,             90),
            (8,             100,             101),
            (9,             100,             70),
            (10,             100,             101);

WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT
           *
           ,lag(TimeSt, 1) OVER(ORDER BY TimeSt) AS LagTimeSt
           ,lag(SetPoint, 1) OVER(ORDER BY TimeSt) AS LagSetPoint
           ,lag(PV, 1) OVER(ORDER BY TimeSt) AS LagPV
         FROM
           MyTable),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT
           *
           ,CASE
              WHEN (PV < SetPoint AND LagPV > LagSetPoint) 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FirstDrop
         FROM
           CTE
         WHERE
          (PV < SetPoint AND LagPV > LagSetPoint)
           OR (PV > SetPoint AND LagPV < LagSetPoint)),
     CTE3
     AS (SELECT
           Lead(timest) OVER(ORDER BY TimeSt) UpTime
           ,*
         FROM
           CTE2)
SELECT
  sum(firstDrop)        AS Occur
  ,sum(uptime - Timest) AS DownTime
FROM
  CTE3 
Where FirstDrop = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lag` to select the previous pv and setpoint values and to only select rows where the current pv is below the setpoint but the previous pv was not below the previous setpoint:

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        lag(Setpoint) over (order by Timestamp) previous_setpoint,
        lag(PV) over (order by Timestamp) previous_pv
    from Table1
) t where PV < Setpoint
and previous_pv >= previous_setpoint
```

To get the duration sum the negative value of the `pv` in the query above i.e. `-t2 -t6 -t9`. The tricky part is for the positive values. For the first row add nothing. For all rows except the first and last, add only the `previous_pv`. For the last row add both `next_pv` and `previous_pv`.

`Timestamp` in row 1,2,3 correspond to t2 t6 t9.
`prev_timestamp` in row 2 corresponds to t5
`prev_timestamp` in row 3 (last row) corresponds to t8
`next_timestamp` in row 3 (last row) corresponds to t10

```
select count(*), sum(case 
            when rn_asc = 1 then -Timestamp
            when rn_desc = 1 then -Timestamp + next_timestamp + prev_timestamp
            else -Timestamp + prev_timestamp
            end)
from (
    select *, 
     row_number() over (order by Timestamp) rn_asc,
     row_number() over (order by Timestamp desc) rn_desc
    from (
        select *,
            lag(Setpoint) over (order by Timestamp) previous_setpoint,
            lag(PV) over (order by Timestamp) previous_pv,
            lag(Timestamp) over (order by Timestamp) prev_timestamp,
            lead(Timestamp) over (order by Timestamp) next_timestamp
        from Table1
    ) t where PV < Setpoint
    and previous_pv >= previous_setpoint
) t
```

Here's a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6ac5/5

Comment: Dont think this is right it gives 83 as the duration i calc it should be 8

Comment: @RegBes  (t5-t2)+(t8-t6)+(t10-t9) = 105-95+101-59+101-70 = 83

Comment: @FuzzyTree he wanted 10-9 + 8-6 + 5-2 the timestamp col

Comment: Thanks @FuzzyTree,
the second part of the query works fine, it gives the right value for number of occurrences. thanks for that.
I think for duration, since the Timestamp is every one second, I can just simply SUM (count ...)  the total number of PV below Setpoint and get total duration, 

but the I am thinking to put the whole lot into dynamic SQL because I have 9 different PVs and 2 setpoint for each PV.
Any comment on that?

Comment: @Farhad which value do you expect for duration in your example? is it 6?

Comment: @FuzzyTree 
the duration is form Timestamp column which is (t5-t2)+(t8-t6)+(t10-t9).

Comment: @Farhad see update, the query now uses the timestamp column for the duration

Comment: @FuzzyTree
the Timestamp is datetime and SUM and Minus operators are invalid for it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical island problem. Steps to solve this problem,

1. Find range start and range end
2. Merge range start and range end into one row
3. Group all by range start

Here is code

```
WITH T0 AS
(
    SELECT [Timestamp], CASE WHEN PV >= SetPoint THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS pvType
    FROM table
),
T1 AS
(
    SELECT [Timestamp], 
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(pvType) OVER(ORDER BY [Timestamp]) = 1 AND pvType = 0 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS pvStart,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(pvType) OVER(ORDER BY [Timestamp]) = 0 AND pvType = 1 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS pvEnd
    FROM T0
),
T2 AS 
(
    SELECT [Timestamp] AS timestampStart, 
        CASE
            WHEN pvEnd = 1 THEN [Timestamp] 
            ELSE LEAD([Timestamp]) OVER(ORDER BY [Timestamp]) 
        END AS timestampEnd, 
        pvStart
    FROM T1
    WHERE pvStart = 1 OR pvEnd = 1
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Occurance, 
    -- Depending Timestamp type, you may want DATEDIFF
    SUM(timestampEnd - timestampStart) AS Duration
FROM T2
WHERE pvStart = 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help. it works good, and looks nice, the only part is, I can't get the Duration, neither SUM nor DATEDIFF are working. the timestamps are datetime.  Any comment?

Comment: Have you tried SUM(DATEDIFF(second, timestampStart, timestampEnd))?

Comment: as i said they datetime type.like below

2017-10-17 09:00:00.000